# How to change Multiple variable values through Serial Monitor

Tags: serial, variables

I am trying ... with minimal success to change/Check and also run voids through the serial monitor .the code i  put i am having probles is that when i am try to send a value larger than 9 the value assigns a diffrent number Ex i set to 200 but arduino sets it as 512.. i got around it deviding the value by 1.6 and got me the new number and only works upto 90 , but i am tryn to see how it should be done correctly...

```
const uint16_t inputLength = 512;
int ss = 0;
int bHold = 0;

void setup() { 
  Serial.begin(9600);
 }

 void loop() {
  if ( Serial.available() > 0 )
  {
    static char input[inputLength];
    static uint16_t i;
    char c = Serial.read();

    if ( c != '\r' && c != '\n' && i < inputLength - 1)
      input[i++] = c;

    else
    {
      input[i] = '\0';
      i = 0;

      uint16_t array[80];
      uint16_t j = 0;

      if ( !strncmp(input, "ss", 2) )
      {        
        char* p = input + 2;
        while ( (p = strchr(p, ' ')) != NULL )
          array[j++] = strtol(p, &p, 10); //< changed from 16

        for ( uint8_t i = 0; i < j; i++ )
        {
          ss = array[i];
          Serial.println(ss);
        }
      }

      if ( !strncmp(input, "bHold", 5) )
      {        
        char* p = input + 5;
        while ( (p = strchr(p, ' ')) != NULL )
          array[j++] = strtol(p, &p, 10);   //< changed from 16

        for ( uint8_t i = 0; i < j; i++ )
        {
         bHold = array[i];
        // bHold=bHold /1.6;            
         Serial.println(bHold);
        }
      }

      if ( !strncmp(input, "Whos There", 10) )
      {
        Serial.print("me");
      }
      if ( !strncmp(input, "hello", 5) )
      {
        Serial.print("hi");
      }
      if ( !strncmp(input, "sa", 2) )
      {
        Serial.print("  ss= ");
        Serial.print(ss);

        Serial.print("  bHold= ");
        Serial.print(bHold);

        Serial.println(" ");
        Serial.println("==============================");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for any tips you can give...

EDIT: I am trying to pass a new value with command on the serial monitor "ss 500"..so that in the arsuino ss = 500. but in this case it makes it equal to 1280.

EDIT2: Chaged the strol to 10...works perfectly ...Thank you TisteAndii!!!!

Comment: What do you mean with "ss = array[i], DEC;". That is "ss=DEC" and gives the same value ss. Should be "ss = array[i]; Serial.println(ss, DEC);"

Comment: Edit the code in your post if you have made any changes to it so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the input string's base to 16 instead of 10 in your `strtol` conversions, which is why you are getting 1280 when you expect 500.

Comment: `Ex i set to 200 but arduino sets it as 512` - TisteAndii is right. 0x200 is 512 in decimal.